# Oraclize computation query. Carriying a formated JSON to nodejs

Tags: json, node.js, docker, ethereum, solidity

I'm using a oraclize computation query to call a dockerfile that launches nodejs and runs a script that calls an API. I'm trying to pass the header as a string variable on the dockerfile and then I format that variable on the js using JSON.parse(). The problem is that, as far as I have tested, every environment uses the string variables differently. JSON.parse() needs a well formated json with internal double quotes but the dockerfile needs the double quotes to start a string variable. When I tested hardcoding the variables if I format the json in the dockerfile like is shown below

```
CMD node index.js "{\"key\":value}"
```

Everything seems to work fine. But if I try to use that in remix or vue the computation query returns an error. (Remix doesn't even let me use a string variable formated like is shown above)

So now I'm completely stuck and don't know how to parse the json through all the environments to the index.js file.

The solidity method:

```
function  request(string _method,string _url,string _header,string _params) payable {
    oraclize_query("computation",[IPFSline,_method,_url,_header,_params]);
}
```

The dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
CMD node index.js $ARG0 $ARG1 $ARG2 $ARG3 && exit 0
```

And the node.js file:

```
const header = process.argv[4];
var options = {
  uri: '',
  method: '',
  time: true
};
options.headers=JSON.parse(header);
```

This is my first question here, I hope I wrote it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you in fact have a number of options here.

1. You can achieve the inner double quotes being escaped, from Solidity -> Oraclize, by simply encompassing them in single quotes, and then just using unescaped quotes in Solidity. Oraclize will automatically add an escape to any double quotes it sees.

   > `oraclize_query("computation", ['fake','{"key":value}']);`
   >   results in `"{\"key\":value}"` in the Oraclize engine as per [API link](https://api.oraclize.it/v1/query/caad2d90657d1a484804bc91c0262d4d9cbe45a388ebc55c2336ea24aaa7cd52/status?_pretty=1)
2. Oraclize already provides an example capable of doing what you need and more, via the same route of using the computation querty, through the Python requests library: [Github repo](https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/master/solidity/computation-datasource/url-requests)